# HTML table with fixed uneven rows

Tags: javascript, html, layout, tablelayout

I'm creating a page that allows the user to select a time slot from a schedule. I would prefer to do this with some sort of table layout (vs. using drop down/combo boxes). But I'm having trouble figuring out which path to take because the schedule is layed out like this.
[image]

So M,W,F are the same and T,TR are the same layout. I was hoping to do this with some sort of table instead of pure graphic because I want to be able to update information displayed in the cells. Is there a method other than doing rowspans to get the uneven layout like the picture. Or should I take a completely different approach. All my javascript needs to know is what information(text) is displayed in the cell and which one is being clicked.

Comment: "R" is the proper abbreviation for Thursday, FYI.

Comment: darkporter: According to who?  R is far less common that Th, or just T.

Comment: @Jeff B: `R` is widely accepted as Thursday, just as `U` is widely accepted as Sunday.. `UMTWRFS` makes much more sense to me than `SMTWTFS`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below is a `TABLE` solution using the [`ROWSPAN`](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html) attribute. CSS is only relied on for setting row heights and column widths.

The big advantage to this approach is that any cells that expand vertically will cause the entire row to expand the same amount, so your columns and rows will never get misaligned.

If you instead try a to use more than one table, or a DIV/CSS-driven solution, you can use Javascript to realign things for you, but this can be quite difficult to implement correctly.

[image]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
            td,th{border:1px solid #000}
            .m,.w,.f{width:104px}
            .t,.r{width:117px}
            .r5{height:12px}
            .r8{height:20px}
            .r9{height:27px}
            .r1,.r10,.r12,.r14{height:60px}
            .r2,.r7,.r11,.r13{height:18px}
            .r3,.r4,.r6{height:40px}            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r1">
                <td class="m"></td>
                <td class="t" rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="w"></td>
                <td class="r" rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="f"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r2">
                <td class="m" rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="w" rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="f" rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r3">
                <td class="t" rowspan="3"></td>
                <td class="r" rowspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r4">
                <td class="m"></td>
                <td class="w"></td>
                <td class="f"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r5">
                <td class="m" rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="w" rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="f" rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r6">
                <td class="t" rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="r" rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r7">
                <td class="m" rowspan="3"></td>
                <td class="w" rowspan="3"></td>
                <td class="f" rowspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r8">
                <td class="t"></td>
                <td class="r"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r9">
                <td class="t" rowspan="3"></td>
                <td class="r" rowspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r10">
                <td class="m"></td>
                <td class="w"></td>
                <td class="f"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r11">
                <td class="m" rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="w" rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="f" rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r12">
                <td class="t" rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="r" rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r13">
                <td class="m" rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="w" rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="f" rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="r14">
                <td class="t"></td>
                <td class="r"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent answer, but consider further - each day is broken up into blocks of time, maybe 15 minute blocks. The thin slice in the middle of Tue/Thu may be 15 min, the block above 45 min, and the one below 75 min. I'd set the rowspan based on 15 min. even if there were no single 15 minute blocks (e.g. rowspan=2 was the smallest time slot). Just a thought.

Comment: @Stephen P: An interesting idea - this makes determining the rowspan value easy, but also means there will be a lot more table rows (e.g., 32 for an 8-hour time span). Not sure which one I prefer in the end.

Comment: Well the time slots don't really fit into a 15 minute interval very well either. So I'm not really concerned with that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/byQHE/

It's not perfect, but it gives you an idea of what you can do.